# how do i reset my data for my div class="col-md-3"

Tags: html, node.js, angular, firebase

So am using a database to store data. and when i enter the data the [div class="col-md-3]

```
   <div class="col-md-3" style="float: right; width: 500px">
      <h2>Content from Firebase</h2>
      <pre *ngFor=

"let item of items | async">{{item.content}}</pre>
</div>
```

stores the data but it doesn't reset when i relaunch the HTML. is there a way to reset this. am new to angular and node so not sure how i implement the function. even better if i can add the code straight to the HTML .

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="float: left">
  <div style="color: blue;">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h3>{{description}}</h3>
  </div>

  <div style="width: 300px;">
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ProductID">Item</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Enter content..." id="ProductID"
               required [(ngModel)]="itemValue" name="Product">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ingredients">Item</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Enter content..." id="ingredients"
               required [(ngModel)]="itemValue2" name="ingredients">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Price">Item</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Enter content..." id="Price"
               required [(ngModel)]="itemValue3" name="Price">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="stock">Item</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Enter content..." id="stock"
               required [(ngModel)]="itemValue4" name="stock">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="health Problems">Item</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Enter content..." id="health Problems"
               required [(ngModel)]="itemValue5" name="health Problems">
      </div>

      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>


</div>


<div class="col-md-3" style="float: right; width: 500px">
  <h2>Content from Firebase</h2>
  <pre *ngFor="let item of items | async">{{item.content}}</pre>
</div>












import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Angular8Firebase';
  description = 'Angular-Fire-Demo';
//realtimedatabase
  itemValue = '';
  itemValue2 = '';
  itemValue3 = '';
  itemValue4 = '';
  itemValue5 = '';
  itemValue6 = '';
  items: Observable<any[]>;
//storage database
  imgSrc = '/assets/img/imgPlaceholder.jpg';
  selectedImage: any = null;
  isSubmitted = false;

   //storage databaseormTemplate = new FormGroup({
    caption : new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    imageUrl : new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  });

 //realtimedatabase
  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = db.list('items').valueChanges();
  }
//realtime database
  onSubmit() {
    this.db.list('items').push({ content: this.itemValue});
    this.db.list('items').push({ content: this.itemValue2});
    this.db.list('items').push({ content: this.itemValue3});
    this.db.list('items').push({ content: this.itemValue4});
    this.db.list('items').push({ content: this.itemValue5});
    this.db.list('items').push({ content: this.itemValue6});
    this.itemValue = '';
    this.itemValue2 = '';
    this.itemValue3 = '';
    this.itemValue4 = '';
    this.itemValue5 = '';
    this.itemValue6 = '';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
 //storage database
  showPreview(event: any) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e: any) => this.imgSrc = e.target.result;
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
      this.selectedImage = event.target.files[0];
    } else {
      this.imgSrc = '/assets/img/imgPlaceholder.jpg';
      this.selectedImage = null;
    }
  }
 //storage database
  onSubmit2(formValue) {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    if (this.formTemplate.value) {
      const filePath = 'images/${this.selectedImage.name}_${new Date().getTime()}';
    }
  }
 //storage database
  get formControls() {
    return this.formTemplate.controls;
  }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean reset?

Comment: i want the display of <div class="col-md-3" to be empty every time i reload the page

Comment: Show us your ts file

Comment: everthing with  //realtimedatabase is realted to the question